# Get Max value in array for loop code VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I got an error info while I use the following code to get Max value in array for loop code.

> Warning 1 Accessing a shared member, constant member, enum member, or nested type through an instance. Regular expressions are not evaluated.

```
Private Sub PicVulGraph_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PicVulGraph.MouseMove
    Me.PicVulGraph.Refresh()

    Dim g As Graphics = Me.PicVulGraph.CreateGraphics
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, e.X, 0, e.X, Me.PicVulGraph.Height)

    Try
        For Each value As Type.Structures.GraphValue In Me._VulGraph
            If e.X < value.x1 Then
                Me.lblPointValueVul.Text = ""
                Me.lblTempVul.Text = ""

            ElseIf e.X > value.x1.MaxValue Then
                Me.lblPointValueVul.Text = ""
                Me.lblTempVul.Text = ""

            ElseIf value.x1 = e.X Then
                Me.lblPointValueVul.Text = value.PointToTime
                Me.lblTempVul.Text = value.Data
                Exit For
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error info occurred from this code

```
value.x1.MaxValue
```

How do I get max value in array for loop code ?

Comment: There are plenty of examples around of getting the smallest or biggest values from an array or list. You need to work on your web searching skills if you haven't found them.

Comment: As for the error message, you're using `Integer.MaxValue`, which is a constant member of the `Integer` type, but accessing it via an `Integer` value. You just use the member of the type, e.g. `If someValue > Integer.MaxValue Then`. That said, what's the point of testing to see if a value is greater than `MaxValue`? By definition, nothing can be greater than the maximum possible value. You are misusing that `MaxValue` because you haven't actually worked out the logic you need to implement before implementing it in code.

Comment: While agree with John that there are countless examples of getting min/max values from arrays all over the internet, back to the actual problem.    Common solution is to call the array Sort() method, then your min value is the first element, the last is the max. or you could use a Linq expression and select the max

Comment: @John : I'm sorry I did not get the point

Comment: @Hursey : I just want to know the max value of value.x1, only that

Comment: @John : When I tried to breakpoint the value.x1 at the maximum line's graph, then the max of value.x1 = 1053. I just want to get this maximum value

Comment: When I posted my first comment, I did a web search and found two examples in less than two minutes. Even more than that if you don't have to use a loop, but you may have to use a loop if this is homework. If I can find them, you can find them. Searching the web takes no programming experience.

Comment: @John : Thank you for your comment, this is not my homework. I'm a new in programming world. Once again thank you.

Comment: @Hursey : Thank you for your idea, I fix it using linq expression and it really works. Dim maxV As Object = (From val As Type.Structures.GraphValue In Me._VulGraph Select val.x1).Last

Comment: I haven't checked, but I would guess there would be a `Max` function in Linq that you could use if you don't want to sort the sequence.